# Storing and reading HTML files in JavaScript using AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to save large amounts of HTML in JavaScript so that I can read it and replace some bits with custom text. I am not sure what's the best way to do this.  I am working on a Serverless infrastructure, i.e. using Lamdba functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "save HTML in Javascript"? You have a webpage and want to extract info and save it as JSON or something? What is the data of the HTML and Javascript you want to produce?

Comment: I would like to save a html file in the project and load it into a javascript variable so that I can change a few bits of it based on some logic.  I want to ideally store these as mustacheJS templates or something similar to be processed in lambda functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can server HTML pages using Lambda functions. You just need to set the headers.

See [this example](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-serve-dynamic-html-via-http-endpoint):

```
module.exports.landingPage = (event, context, callback) => {
  let dynamicHtml = '<p>Hey Unknown!</p>';
  // check for GET params and use if available
  if (event.queryStringParameters && event.queryStringParameters.name) {
    dynamicHtml = `<p>Hey ${event.queryStringParameters.name}!</p>`;
  }

  const html = `
  <html>
    <style>
      h1 { color: #73757d; }
    </style>
    <body>
      <h1>Landing Page</h1>
      ${dynamicHtml}
    </body>
  </html>`;

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    },
    body: html,
  };

  // callback is sending HTML back
  callback(null, response);
};
```

Or you could return a JSON object, as Lambda functions are commonly used, and this JSON object would have a HTML string set as one of the properties.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript based HTML templating library such as [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to compile and upload HTML templates in the form of JavaScript dependancies along with Lambda code.

This allows replacing parts in your HTML using placeholders which is easy to maintain.

Comment: I've been trying to do something like this using another templating engine - Nunjucks but for some reason, it can't find the directory that I've placed my HTML files in. Could you provide some sample code on how this can be done?

Comment: Did you check whether the file paths are correct?

Comment: The path was correct. I just had to figure out how to include my .html files in the build folder - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075719/6644114