# How to use an HTML templating engine with a Node.js function in an AWS lambda?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, aws-lambda, templating

I have a lambda function that is supposed to return an HTML page.

This page needs a number of dynamic variables as well as custom stylesheets to function properly.

I have tried the regular way of returning HTML as a string, setting the correct content-type and substituting the dynamic variables I need within that string. **This works.**

However, I want to use a templating engine rather than writing out strings of HTML as Javascript.

I've tried using [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html) but it's unable to find my HTML file since the build folder only has an app.js in it.

Comment: You need to add all modules to the lamda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html

Comment: I'm actually using cdk deploy to deploy my stack. I'm not really directly updating my aws function anywhere. To be honest, the CDK bit is kind of a black box to me as well.

Comment: Not sure what "Lambda function spun up on the fly using the CDK" means. Are you saying you are just giving it a single nodejs script file to deploy? You probably need to be bundling your Lambda function into a deployment .zip file, and configuring the CDK to deploy that instead.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to learn CDK if you intend to use it, or hire someone to write the code if you prefer to keep this black box closed. This is the first search result of how to use CDK to deploy npm dependencies https://github.com/AntoniusGolly/cdk-lambda-typescript-boilerplate Vivisect it, learn and apply to your usecase. It still does the same thing as in the article - installs dependencies, zips them, and pushes to aws.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help anyway. I will see if I can configure the CDK to deploy a .zip file instead of what it's currently doing.

Comment: So, it turns out the file zipping and uploading to AWS was already happening. I just didn't know. What I had to end up doing is adding a copy command to the build command and actually copy my html files to the build output folder. Probably not a long-term solution but it fixed my issue.

Comment: Great stuff! I encourage you to post your finding as an answer, if anybody faces the same issue and seeks for an advice from the community

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your files are part of the bundle being uploaded to AWS, here's how I fixed the issue of the HTML file not being found:

The output of my `esbuild` is just a single app.js file and this is what was originally being pushed to AWS. I had to add a `cp` command to my build phase which copies all my .html files from my working directory to the build directory.

Once this is done, you can simply refer to your .html files using a combination of `path` and `__dirname` and Nunjucks (or any other templating engine) should be able to find your files without any issues.